# How can I get a music streaming service of my choice work as an app?

Tags: software-recommendation, music, music-player

Spotify has launched a dedicated Ubuntu player some time ago... but it doesnt make any difference to me as my country doesn't have spotify...

though it does have many music streaming services of its own! 
Nuvola players also doesn't include those services... I tried fogger but the services need flash support...

How can I get any of them working on Ubuntu?

Note: i am using spotify as an example( to indicate a family of online music streeming services), coz spotify has a standalone app.I **DO NOT WANT TO USE SPOTIFY**

Answer (score 1):

Possibly by using a VPN or getting a SSH shell account somewhere and use it as a proxy with the -D flag.

Comment: Nono! u got me wrong...using them in my country is not a problem...i dont want to use services that are not available in my country... i want that i should b able to use any of the ones available in my country like an app/music player...like for e.g. the way spotify has a standalone app...that way...or like nuvola player!

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand why not use Spotify of Nuvola? Do you want to play local music files too?

Comment: I dont want to use spotify at all!! i am using it only as an example.. I live in India and i want to use this service - http://gaana.com/#!/home ...so now, i want to bring down this interface to my desktop...like i would do using fogger...but it needs flash...so fogger cant handle it!